# sudo: setrlimit(8): Invalid argument after switching Mac OS shell from BASH to ZSH

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, sudo, zsh

After updating to Mac OS Catalina some months ago, I followed the prompted suggestions and changed my shell from BASH to ZSH.

Since that time, whenever I use sudo in Terminal, I get `sudo: setrlimit(8): Invalid argument`. The sudo'd command runs fine, but this error shows every time.

I don't have any plugins or modifications to my shell - it's vanilla ZSH in default Terminal.app

I've searched the Googs but I can't really find anything that seems like a good match - only generic "increasing limits on sockets in osx". I could try that, but I don't understand why I should be having an issue in the first place when I have not and do not doing anything peculiar or fancy with shell - I use it for git, npm and occasionally other commands.

Does anyone have any ideas? Not sure what other information you'd need, but let me know if there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this message as well.

I think I've might have worked out a solution to it.

Check which version of `sudo` you have installed with `sudo -V` and if it isn't 1.8.31 download the newest version from here [GitHub](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/releases)
You'll have to download this one here "sudo-1.8.31.mac1015.pkg"

Let me know if it worked out for you!

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Wouldn't have thought to manually update sudo. 